# Bootstrap collapse accordion bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying this accordion:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

If you are very fast clicking in the second tab before the first is not completely opened (ex. using keyboard and mouse), you will get two open panels... this is not an accordion!

I would like to know if is there any known workaround.

Comment: on `show.bs.collapse` action try to hidden all panels except your panel.

Comment: I found an opened issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13447